# cakephp Auth Login through Session

Tags: php, session, cakephp, authentication, oauth

I am trying to login to a `CakePHP` app through session with `credentials` created from external custom `PHP` code. But I am unable to figure out how to do this exactly. I don't want to do it with form.

For example:
I am logged in at site A and my `CakePHP` app is site B (both hosted on same server, but in different folders).

I have retrieved the `username/password` set from site A into B.

But I don't know that now how to use this in site B.

Any thought on the same ?

Thanks.

Note:
Well I am receiving the username in CakePHP session 
i.e `$this->Session->read('Username');`

Now want to login through Auth
e.g `$this->Auth->login($this->Session->read('Username'));`
So that I can then get user through $this->Auth->user();

Can you help me in that?
I am doing this in AppController, method: beforeFilter() , _checksession()

Comment: Code example will explain at glance can you add few.

Comment: @Arun_C_C I now tried to explain above in Note section.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the username and password sent from site A, couldn't you just verify the credentials against the database again? Or create a table that stores sessions and link them to the usernames and just pass that session variable through the PHP $_SESSION variable

SITE A:

```
session_start();
$this->Session->write('session','ABCDEFGHIJKL12345' ); // random generated string
// store in DB
```

and then when you get to site B:

SITE B:

```
session_start();
// if  $this->Session->read('session') == '' force login again
//else

//compare the session in the db and check for valid session

//if valid

//load page.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the username/password in the session as you say, try building a User model data array which Auth will then try to automatically verify for you:

```
// Construct model data array like what AuthComponent would usually expect
$userData = array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => $this->Session->read('username'), // Use your stored values (change as appropriate)
        'password' => $this->Session->read('password')
    )
);

// Attempt to authenticate the user
if ($this->Auth->login($userData)) {

    // Login worked

} else {

    // Login failed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,
I got a solution that rather then sending the password, i only send username and after proper validation i try to login as:

```
$username = $this->Session->read('userName');
//validation
$user = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('username'=>"$username")));

$this->Session->write('Auth',$user);

//now I can use: 
$this->Auth->login()
```

Previously I was saving session at wrong index.